# Problems with accessing external content as sudo/root

Tags: debian, firewall, sudo, curl

System environment: VM running under Debian 9, firewall is iptables. UFW, etc not installed.

I run into problems when spinning up a kubernetes cluster by executing `sudo kubeadm init`. The call causes a timeout. When I try to access

```
curl https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable-1.txt
```

this works fine with my local user, but runs as well into timeout if I am using sudo/root. The same is true for communication through port 80/http. I assume the firewall is misconfigured, but I am not sure about this. What do I have to do to enable the access to external content for sudo/root? How can I investigate this issue?

I do have sudo access to the VM but am not an experienced linux admin and the VM as such is managed by another team.